# How to install openflow on Ubuntu

Tags: openflow

I want to install openflow on ubuntu, but I find that there are many ways to install openflow. How to start the openflow by one controller and one switch. If possible, give me a demon could run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mininet installation:

```
http://mininet.org/download/
```

Follow:

```
Option 2: Native Installation from Source
```

Then on the terminal (for one controller, one switch, two hosts):

```
sudo mn
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get started with OpenFlow is to [use the Mininet emulator](http://mininet.org/walkthrough/). On Ubuntu, you can install it with: `apt install mininet`.

Answer (score 0):

1-A Switch openflow capable, try Open V Switch
apt install openvswitch-switch

2-A SDN Controller , try OpenDaylight
Nitrogen stable SR3

wget https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/0.7.3/karaf-0.7.3.tar.gz

tar xvf karaf karaf-0.7.3.tar.gz
./bin/karaf

## Install features

feature:install odl-restconf odl-l2switch-switch #BASIC NEEDED

feature:install odl-dlux-core odl-dluxapps-yangui  #GUI STUFF

enjoy